# How to find and replace html data using data-id attribute?

Tags: jquery

I want to make a live update function, when a user click on the selected element, he gets a modal popup, and can do changes to the text selected.

So far im able to update the html, but both colums update. is there somway to update only the element clicked? element holds the data-id, but how to update the correct id?

**the modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editBox">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="editBox">Edit</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea class="form-control htmldata"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So far i have this html:**

```
<h1 class="edit" data-id="1">Test</h1>
<div class="edit" data-id="2">
   my content here
</div>
```

**So far this is the jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $('.edit').click(function(e){

        var element = $(this);
        var page = 'home';

        $('#editBox').modal('show');

        var data = (
            {
                'id':element.data("id"),
                'page': page
            }
        );

        $('.save').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            element.html($('.htmldata').val());
            $('#editBox').modal('hide');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide us an live example ?

Comment: most of it is aboue, i dint include modal itself. when u click save,i need to update the data of clicked element

Comment: $('.htmldata') where you are using this class in HTML?

Comment: added all of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update and move scripts into snippet.**

```js
var element = null;
$('.edit').click(function(e){
        element = $(this);
        var page = 'home';

        $('#editBox').modal('show');
        $('textarea.htmldata').val(element.text());

        $('.save').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            element.html($('.htmldata').val());
            $('#editBox').modal('hide');
        });

    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editBox">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="editBox">Edit</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea class="form-control htmldata"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<h1 class="edit" data-id="1">Test</h1>
<div class="edit" data-id="2">
   my content here
</div>
```

Comment: Seams that it only work on the first element, after editing element two it also updates the first one.

Comment: have you try? `$('.edit[data-id="' + element.data('id') + '"]')` has mean "search object wich has `.edit` class, and has attribute `data-id` where the value depend on `element.data('id')`.

Comment: Yes, when i reopen modal and typ in value it replaces both id 1 and 2, does the modal hold old id as default?

Comment: edit the first one, and then edit the 2th, then both is updated with the last.

Comment: @sdfgg45: Look at my edited answer - `e.currentTarget` should do the trick

Comment: Edit the h1 by clicking on it, and set a new value and then click save, then do the same with the 2th div. it wil then give the value to both of the elements, h1 and div. i need them to be separate.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, The problem is on `element` Object declare position. Check for my new update. @sdfgg45

Answer (score 2):

**edited after seeing entire html:**
After seeing the updated html, simply replace `var element = $(this);` with `var element = $(e.currentTarget);`.

[`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) refers to the element the event was attached to, so will always be the element with the `edit` class, unlike `e.target`, which is the actual element you clicked on (this may be a child element of the element with the `edit` class.

Hope this helps

Comment: when i click on a element that element has a id, i need to replace the spesific html code/content of that spesific id.